# Difference (if any) between SMAJ58A and SMAJ58A-13-F

Tags: pcb, diodes

I have a BOM that I am supposed to model, but I don't see any available footprint for these diodes that I am coming across. Funny thing is they all are available with the xxx-13-F after the manufacturer identifier.

The component listed is the [SMAJ58A](https://www.diodes.com/part/view/SMAJ58A), the component I found is the [SMAJ58A-13-F](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/diodes-incorporated/smaj58a-13-f/1934273).

The components on their site list this as well. I am just confused.

Why not list SMAJ58A-13-F in the BOM? Would that mean use any variation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diodes uses these numbers/letters to designate product packing:

https://www.diodes.com/design/support/frequently-asked-questions/#faq-679

> > When suffixes are appended to part numbers, what do they signify?
>
> At Diodes Incorporated, dash numbers / letters are appended to our product part numbers (example: ZMM5250B-7) to indicate package type and reel size, as listed below.
>
> A = Ammo Pack 
> B = Bulk Packaging 
> T = Tape & Reel 
> U = Tube Packaging 
> 7 = 7-inch Reel 
> 13 = 13-inch Reel 
> F = Pb Free or Pb Free Lead Finish (as noted on associated data sheets) 
> L = (Analog) Pb Free 
> G = (Analog) Pb Free and Green 
> TA, TC = Refers to the tape and reel option of the part. Note: These suffixes are not shown on our Data Sheets and other marketing materials. They are not needed for part number searches on our website.

The base part number is just that, the base; it isn't orderable directly from Diodes, Inc. that way.  Whether distributors or CMs (contract manufacturers) use the same terminology in their catalogs, or honor it for sake of consistency, or ignore it for sake of universality, is up to them.  (CMs generally shy away from substituting inexact part numbers, as manufacturers use all manner of codes (and sometimes none at all!) to denote revisions both major and minor, as well as more mundane differences like packing.)

Other manufacturers have other numbering schemes, of course.

Comment: Well detailed answer, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

They link to the same datasheet, they are the same. Use whatever suffix your distributor (the place you want it purchased from) uses.